# Finding integers that are divisible by 6 or 7 but not both

Tags: java, integer-division

I am trying to write a program that displays the integers between 1 and 100 that are divisible by either 6 or 7 **but not both**.

Here is my code:

```
import acm.program.*;

public class Problem4 extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            boolean num = ((i % 6 == 0) || (i % 7 == 0));

            if (num == true)
            println(i + " is divisible");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code shows the following answers:
6,7,12,14,18,21,24,28,30,35,36,**42**,48,49,54,56,60,63,66,70,72,77,78,**84**,90,91,96,98

Now the bold numbers 42 and 84 are both divisbile by 6 and 7. Now If I change the `||` to `&&` in the above code, the result shows only 42 and 84.

What change should I do to remove these 2 numbers from the final result?

Comment: you should change the `num == true` to just `num`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to make your condition look like:

```
boolean num = (i % 6 == 0 || i % 7 == 0) && !(i % 6 == 0 && i % 7 == 0);
```

that's basically converting "*but not both*" to Java code :)

Comment: You can almost translate it to words: (divisible-by-6 OR divisible-by-7) AND NOT (divisible-by-6 AND divisible-by-7)

Comment: Thanks Yuval, that helps as well.

Comment: Why not use the XOR operator "a ^ b" which is equivalent to "(a || b) && !(a && b)"

Answer (score 19):

XOR is the way to go.

```
import acm.program.*;

public class Problem4 extends ConsoleProgram {
  public void run() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      if ( (i % 6 == 0) ^ (i % 7 == 0) ) {
        println(i + " is divisible");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I will return my developer license.

Comment: My book only defines 3 logical operators:
1). !
2). &&
3). ||

It did not mention XOR (^)

Comment: Xor is a binary operator. A ^ B means A or B but not both. != can be used as equivalent on booleans if ^ looks too alien to you, Ibn Saeed.

Comment: Took the code right out of my editor. Just one note though: It is bad style (in Java) to explicitly test a boolean expression. "if (i % 6 == 0 ^ i % 7 == 0) ..." is preferred.

Comment: @ggf31416, removed the (== true). Thanks for pointing that out for me.

Comment: XOR is used seldom enough where most people wound have to look it up to remember it.  That's why I'd prefer my way - more readable, and exactly the same thing logically.  BTW, it's "Stanford".

Comment: @myself - it's "would", not "wound".  8)

Comment: @duffymo, I guess it depends on what kind of development work you do.  I use XOR a lot in the lower level programming I do.

Comment: -1. Sorry I had to do this to have your attention. I you can convince me you came to the same conclusion independently after 4 minutes of my own post, I will revoke my downvote. Don't worry, you lost only -2 rep and you still gained +120 btw. Have a nice day ^_^

Comment: @duffymo: This is why they don't use XOR gates to build chips, or use XOR for cryptographic purposes. Not to mention image manipulation through XOR. "Make everything as simple as possible, but not simpler." - Albert Einstein ;)

Comment: @kd304 - no worries.  My notary public wasn't available when I posted the answer, but I will point out that mine is listed as "older" because I posted first.  I had to edit because I erroneously hit the "return" key before adding that last clause.  As I recall, by the time I typed in the comments pointing out my error and entering the "(i % 42 !- 0)" bit, your answer was up.  I don't mind the criticism though, because I actually like the XOR answer better.  No problem.  Sincerely, %

Comment: @kd304 - Can't go wrong with an Einstein quote.  And your answer is superior to mine.  Ups for you.

Comment: @duffymo: See my last comment on your answer - I hope you recognize it from somewhere. There is always time to improve an answer (^_^)

Comment: @kd304 Simultaneity is a hard question in the web world.  As I was typing my answer, I saw the banner up top about another answer to the question being posted.  I didn't refresh the answer list because I didn't want to lose my work (even though it was just a few minutes.)  These things happen, and priority isn't a crucial issue, so I'm not too concerned about it.

Comment: @mtnygard: Ok. I made a mistake. Forgot that the site does not allow the vote to be rewoked when the post itself was edited too long ago. I don't know how we could achieve 'simultaneity' on this matter but I really want to. I can't promise I'll keep on track with this post. But thank you, I'll repay you somehow.

Comment: @kd304 - No worries at all.  I got what I wanted out of this - a fine conversation and learning experience.  I'm happy to take instruction from you.

Comment: operator_logical_XOR(a^b) = ( (a || b) && !(a && b) ) in java notation for logical_or(||) and logical_and(&&)

Answer (score 5):

You need an extra check for "but not both".  I think it should be:

boolean num = ((i % 6 == 0) || (i % 7 == 0))  && (i % 42 != 0);

Comment: I already have that in my code


boolean num = ((i % 6 == 0) || (i % 7 == 0));

Comment: Hit the enter too quickly.  See edited result.  Your problem isn't Java, it's logic.

Comment: But your code is more of a hack rather than a solution as 42 and 84 are not known in advance.

Comment: yes they are.  "but not both" says it all.  mine will catch 42, 84, and every other multiple of 6*7.  That's what "but not both" means.

Comment: I like this.  42 isn't a hack, as suggested above.  It's the LCM of 6 and 7, so any number that's divisible by 42 will, of course, be divisible by _both_ 6 and 7.  Nice.

Comment: Thanks, i tested the code and it worked. A very different way of solving this problem.

Comment: -1 from me. I would not recommend that anybody use the Java language this way, even if it "works". Any decent language version should be able to handle the logical issue in a way that doesn't require this measure.

Comment: I'm sorry, I changed my mind about the -1 but I can't remove it as the system disallows the rewoke on older posts. I'll therefore make a fav+upvote on one of your questions.

Answer (score 5):

you can also try

```
boolean num = ((i % 6 == 0) != (i % 7 == 0));
```

Comment: For booleans, ^ does the same thing as != (see truth tables). After all, logical bicondition (xnor) is logical equality, and exclusive or is its negation. I happen to prefer !=, mainly because some languages I use don't have boolean xor, and != more-than-suffices. Many of the other examples include duplicate mod calculations, which is not terrible, but mod can slow tight code down :)

Comment: wonderful....... with just NOT_EQUAL to operator and mod... XOR of two no. implementation.......

Answer (score 2):

Think about what it means to be divisible by 6 and 7... the answer to life the universe and everything.

Comment: "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy" rocks)

Answer (score 1):

```
import acm.program.*;

public class Problem4 extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            boolean num = ((i % 6 == 0) || (i % 7 == 0));
            boolean both = ((i % 6 == 0) && (i % 7 == 0));

            if ((num == true) &&  (both == false))
            println(i + " is divisible");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that should work as well- in C++ but change to boolean...

```
int value;
if ((value % 6 == 0 && value % 7 != 0) || (value % 6 != 0 && value % 7 == 0))
    cout << "Is " << value << " divisible by 6 or 7, but not both? true" << endl;
  else
    cout << "Is " << value << " divisible by 6 or 7, but not both? false" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

**A little simplified version**

```
for(int i=1; i<=100; i++) {

            // Either Divisible by 6 or 7 but not both


            if((i%6==0 && i%7!=0) ||( i%7==0 && i%6!=0)) {


                println(i);
```

Comment: please explain what you had answered.